# How to convert character encoding with Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, encoding

I am currently having trouble with results from the Amazon API.

The service returns a string with unicode characters: *Learn Objective\xE2\x80\x93C on the Mac (Learn Series)*

With Ruby 1.9.1 the string could not even been processed:

```
REXML::ParseException: #<Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible encoding regexp match (UTF-8 regexp with ASCII-8BIT string)>

...

Exception parsing

Line: 1

Position: 1636

Last 80 unconsumed characters:

Learn Objective–C on the Mac (Learn Series)
```

Comment: I highly recommend reading *The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)* ( http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html ), even if you're already familiar with encodings and such.

Comment: i recently read yehuda katz's article about encoding in 1.9 and thought: WTF?! (http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/17/encodings-unabridged/)

the article you linked is excelent.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As the exception points, your string is ASCII-8BIT encoded. You should change the encoding. There is a [long story](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_string) about that, but if you are interested in quick solution, just `force_encoding` on the string before you do any processing:

```
s = "Learn Objective\xE2\x80\x93C on the Mac"
# => "Learn Objective\xE2\x80\x93C on the Mac"
s.encoding
# => #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
s.force_encoding 'utf-8'
# => "Learn Objective–C on the Mac"
```

Comment: is this an issue of the response that is sent from the amazon-service? should it have set another content-type?

Comment: I didn't work with AWS so I don't know how that string has been loaded, but you can set the default encoding on (Ruby) application level, so chances are that it would solve the issue - more on the link in the answer. BTW, I don't think there is an _issue_ at all, Ruby simply doesn't (and shouldn't) try to guess which encoding the string it is receiving is in.

Comment: Probably; that would mean HTTParty should take care of it.

Answer (score 25):

Mladen's solution works if everything that is encoded in ASCII-8BIT can actually be converted directly to UTF-8. It breaks when there are characters that are 1) invalid, or 2) undefined in UTF-8. However, this will work (in 1.9.2 and up:

```
new_str = s.encode('utf-8', 'binary', :invalid => :replace, 
  :undef => :replace, :replace => '')
```

ASCII-8BIT is effectively binary. This code converts the encoding to UTF-8, while properly dealing with invalid and undefined characters. The :invalid option specifies that invalid characters be replaced. The :undef option specifies that undefined characters be replaced. And the :replace option defines what the invalid or undefined characters should be replaced with. In this case, I opted to simply remove them.

Comment: uh, looks nice! will try that!

Comment: did you try the `:fallback` mechanism? i tried to replace some `windows-1252` encodings like `u00E4` for ä but it didn't work out :(

Comment: This just saved the day for me when streaming a file into an HTTP body for posting... Many thanks! +1

Comment: This worked for me to remove a very troubling BOM character