# How do I encode files to UTF-8 for Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, encoding, chardet

I've been working on outlook imports (linked in exports to outlook format) but I'm having  troubles with encoding. The outlook format CSV I get from exporting my LinkedIn contacts are not in UTF-8.  Letters like `ñ` cause an exception in the `mongoid_search` gem when calling `str.to_s.mb_chars.normalize`. I think encoding is the issue, because when I call `mb_chars` ([see first code example](http://apidock.com/rails/String/mb_chars)). I am not sure if this is a bug in the gem, but I was advised to sanitize the data nonetheless.

From File Picker, I tried using their new, community-supported gem to upload CSV data. I tried three encoding detectors and transcoders:

1. Ruby port of a Python lib `chardet`

   - Didn't work as expected
   - The port still contained Python code, preventing it from running in my app
2. `rchardet19` gem

   - Detected `iso-8859` with `.8/1` confidence.
   - Tried to transcode with Iconv, but crashed on "illegal characters" at `ñ`
3. [`Charlock_Holmes`](https://github.com/brianmario/charlock_holmes) gem

   - Detected `windows-1252` with `33/100` confidence
   - I assume that's the actual encoding, and `rchardet` got `iso-8859` because this ones based of that.
   - This gem uses ICU and has a maintained branch "bundle-icu" which supports Heroku. When I try to transcode using `charlock`, I get the error `U_FILE_ACCESS_ERROR`, an ICU error code meaning "could not open file"

Anybody know what to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby 1.9 has encoding built in, have you tried:

```
s.force_encoding 'utf-8'
```

mb_chars is a wrapper for ruby 1.8, so you shouldn't need it.

See duplicate

[how to convert character encoding with ruby 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159742/how-to-convert-character-encoding-with-ruby-1-9)