# Ruby Encoding Issue With CSV and Byte Order Mark

Tags: ruby, csv, encoding

I have the following code to download a windows-generated CSV file with a byte order mark.

```
  res = HTTParty.get(url, :format => :text)
  res.body.sub!(/^\xEF\xBB\xBF/, '') #Remove BOM
```

Running this exact code in the console, throws the following:

```
Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible encoding regexp match (UTF-8 regexp with ASCII-8BIT string)
```

but running it from within a class method works.

What could this be?

Comment: I bet you're using Ruby 1.9. Take a look at [how to convert character encoding with ruby 1.9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159742/how-to-convert-character-encoding-with-ruby-1-9) for instance.

Comment: Character encoding in Ruby (1.9+) is contextual (i.e. what the default character set in use is depends on lexical and variable scope). Also, you may not need to explicitly remove the BOM, because Ruby's `csv` library can accept a parameter to do that for you.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. 

Neil Slater - So am I understanding correctly that the contextual encoding when executing something in my console is different than the encoding used when executing in the scope of a class method? How do I find out the encoding being used? It's strange as the string encoding comes back as "ASCII-8BIT" in both executions.

toch - I can convert the encoding to UTF-8 and no longer receive the error but am trying to understand why different behavior exists between a class method and my console.